# Why $\dim V = \dim (\ker T^n) + \dim (\text{range} T^n)$ does this mean $V = \ker T^n \oplus \operatorname{range} T^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, self-learning

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$.

If

$$\dim V = \dim(\ker T^n \oplus \operatorname{range} T^n) 
= \dim (\ker T^n) + \dim (\operatorname{range} T^n),$$

why does this mean $V = \ker T^n \oplus \operatorname{range} T^n$?

I am self-studying *Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right*. I am a bit confused, could someone please guide me towards a rigorous proof. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, more generally, the dimension of the intersection then is zero, hence we have equality. Remember that $W=U\oplus V$ means $W=U+V$ and $U\cap V=0$. See [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionsformel).

Comment: @DietrichBurde i understand their dimensions may add up to be equal and their intersections might be the 0 vector, but my point of confusion is , how come the vector spaces itself  become equal to each other. Could you write the statement of the general result you are refering to please. thanks

Comment: What other $\operatorname{dim}(V)$-dimensional vector spaces are there in $V$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams None other than $V$ and $\ker T^n +$ range $T^n$

Comment: I suggest you look at a few examples and see why this might be true. I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding how vector subspaces work.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Sure  I will. I do have an intuition why the result is true. What is probably of concern me is that I do not have a rigorous way to prove it

Comment: @DietrichBurde From what I understand, the link you shared suggests in one direction only that if $V$ is a direct sum of $U_1$ and $U_2$, then $\dim V = \dim U_1+ \dim U_2$. Is the converse always true? For the converse to hold true, wouldn't we need to first prove that V = U_1 + U_2

Comment: If (and only if) $\dim (U_1 + U_2) = \dim U_1 + \dim U_2$, then the sum is direct. [Since we're talking about finite-dimensional spaces, it's not so for infinite-dimensional ones.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W \leq V$ be a subspace with $\dim W = \dim V = n$. Then $W = V$.

**Proof:** Assume to the contrary that $W \subsetneq V$. Then we can pick $w \in V \setminus W$. Take a basis $\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ of $W$. Then $\{w,w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ is a linearly independent set of $n+1$ elements in $V$, which is impossible since $\dim V = n$. Thus, we must have $W = V$. $\quad \square$

Now apply this with $W = \ker T^n \oplus \operatorname{range} T^n \leq V$.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Got it